# Javascript Local Variable Not Updated

Tags: javascript, geolocation, local-variables

I have coded this function to detect and update postLat and postLon variables.

```
function searchAddSubmit(){
    var shopId = 1; //random number to test the function
    var postLon, postLat;
    var shopTime = $("#selected-search-result-minutes").val();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        postLat=position.coords.latitude;
        postLon=position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(postLat);
        console.log(postLon);
        console.log('reun');
    },function(error){});
    console.log(postLat+" 1231");
    console.log(postLon+" 1231");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search-add-process.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data:{
            id: shopId,
            time: shopTime, //this value is taken from a form input
            lat: postLat,
            lon: postLon
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.error === true) {
                alert(data.msg);
            } else {
                alert(data.msg);
                //remove output when successful
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I used Chrome's Javascript Console tool to examine the variables (as printed with `console.log()`) and this is the result:

```
undefined 1231
undefined 1235
1.2957797
103.8501069
ruen
```

Coming to this point, I have these questions:

1. Why are the variables `postLon` and `postLat` are not updated? In fact, the undefined variables are passed over to `search-add-process.php` in the ajax block, not the actual values.
2. Why `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function runs after the `console.log(postLat+" 1231")` line? Correct me if I am wrong, I always assumed that Javascript would execute line by line.

Comment: Is `getCurrentPosition()` an AJAX call? The callback function you've provided into it might run after the `console.log()` calls are made.

Comment: @Blender, `getCurrentPosition()` belongs to Geolocation API, new in HTML5.

Comment: @Blender, you can have a look at the Geolocation API at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation). :)

Comment: **This initiates an asynchronous request to detect the user's position**. That's asynchronous as well, so the same problem applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first tell the Geolocation API to try to find the current position of the user, and you let it go and search while you do the rest of your work. This is called **Asynchronous Execution**. In other words, you let the Geolocation API take its time to search and find the place of the user, while you do the rest of your job (rest of your code is getting executed). Then when the API found the position, it executes the function you've passed to it.

Take the code of ajax into the **success callback** and everything would be fine.

Comment: But what if the latlon cannot be retrieved, won't the ajax codes not run? `postLat` and `postLon` is meant to track the user's location when they input the shop's timing (it is meant to be used to track part-timers while they are on the ground roving).

Answer (score 0):

Place the whole `$.ajax({...});` call within the `getCurrentPosition` callback function;
e.g. place it directly before or after the line `console.log('reun');`